# Get time inside a accordion

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I´m trying to make to implement a date inside my accordion underneath some text.

The text and the image are inserted by a user in the article section in wordpress and the date should always appear under the text. But it keeps giving errors and is always in 1970.

The code below:

```
<?php
add_shortcode("accordion_news","accordion_news");
function accordion_news($attr){
$posts = getPostsByCategoryName($attr['category-name']);
$html = "";
foreach ($posts as $key => $post)
{
$html .= '<div class="news-vaga">
            <div>
              <div class="arrow-news"></div>
              <h4 class="button-click uppercase candidatura-border">'.$post->post_title.'</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="news-vaga-container">
              <p>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-xxs-12">
                '.getImgTagByPostAttachment($post->ID).'
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-xxs-12">
                <span>'.apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content).'</span>
                <div>'. date("d F Y", strtotime($data->post_date)).'</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>';
}
  return $html;
}
 ?>
```

And this is what appear on the page:

[image]

Comment: So re-act on the error messages. Why is `$data` not defined? You need it for the DATE. Second message depends on the first error message. So fix that first.

Comment: Solution: change  `date("d F Y", strtotime($data->post_date))` to `date("d F Y", strtotime($post->post_date))`

Comment: Shouldn’t it rather be `$post->post_date` than `$data->post_date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luis

Please use

'. date("d F Y", strtotime($post->post_date)).'

at the place of

'. date("d F Y", strtotime($data->post_date)).'

.because there is nothing in $data variable.and it is not declare anywhere.

I hope it will help you.
:)